# How to compute the implicit function f in $\int^\infty_{-\infty} g(m,t)f(t)dt = a\cdot 10^{bm}$ for g gaussian.

Tags: integration

Let $g(x,m) = e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ for a given $\sigma$, $a$ and $b$ are given too.

Is there a way to get at the function $f$ such that

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} g(m,t)f(t)dt = a\cdot 10^{bm}$$

and, if there is, is there a way to get at $f$, if the right side of the equation is any given function in $m$?

Comment: Use Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote
$$G(t)=\exp \left( -\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$
then $g(m,t)=G(m-t)$ and your problem can be written as, with $h(m)=a 10^{bm}$

> Find $f$ such that for all $m$
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(m-t) f(t) dt = h(m)$$
>   i.e denoting by $*$ the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) such that
>   $$ (G * f)(m)=h(m). \tag{1}$$

This formulation is why the comments propose to use a Fourier transform with respect to $m$. As the Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms, we obtain
$$\widehat{G}(\xi) \cdot \widehat{f}(\xi) =\widehat{h}(\xi)$$ 
i.e 
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\widehat{G}(\xi)^{-1} \widehat{h}(\xi).$$

The Fourier transform of a Gaussian is well known, more precisely
$$\widehat{G}(\xi) = \sigma \exp \left( -\frac{\sigma^2 \xi^2}{2} \right)$$
so
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sigma} \exp \left( \frac{\sigma^2 \xi^2}{2} \right) \widehat{h}(\xi).$$

The difficulty is to have a $h$ such that the previous expression has a Fourier inverse (as it is not the case for any $h$).

For exemple if $b=-i \omega$ one obtains
$$\widehat{h}(\xi)=\sqrt{2 \pi} \delta_{\ln(10) \omega}(\xi)$$
so
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)= \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi} a}{\sigma} \exp \left( \frac{\sigma^2 (\ln(10) \omega)^2}{2} \right) \delta_{\ln(10) \omega}(\xi)$$
i.e
$$f(t)= \frac{ a}{\sigma} \exp \left( \frac{\sigma^2 (\ln(10) \omega)^2}{2} \right) 10^{-i \omega t}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is the  ? Is there no fourier inverse for b and a in R?

Comment: The $\delta$ is the [Dirac mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). The problem if $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is that you are not in the space of [tempered distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distribution) so it is dangerous to use Fourier Transform.